# Issue in building SLES15 Image with KIWI + OpenSUSE13.2

Tags: docker, opensuse, sles, ikiwiki

I am new to Kiwi and Linux. I am trying to build a SLES 15 SP4 image from openSUSE13.2 machine through Docker 1.91

Docker base is SLES15SP4 with Kiwi 9.24.

openSUSE machine does not have internet and repos point to a local network machine.

When I try to build a image, it is stuck at 0% as below, there are no errors.

Please let me know if I am missing something or where to look for.

```
[ DEBUG ]: 03:22:44 | EXEC: [chroot /workspace/main-image/src/kiwi/build/build zypper --non-interactive --gpg-auto-import-keys --pkg-cache-dir /var/cache/kiwi/packages --reposd-dir /var/cache/kiwi/zypper/repos --solv-cache-dir /var/cache/kiwi/zypper/solv --cache-dir /var/cache/kiwi/zypper --raw-cache-dir /var/cache/kiwi/zypper/raw --config /kiwi_md6tikq3 install --download in-advance --auto-agree-with-licenses --no-recommends -- aaa_base-extras bash-completion checkmedia chrony cron cryptsetup dhcp-client dialog-lang dos2unix dracut-kiwi-oem-dump dracut-kiwi-oem-repart dracut-sshd firewalld fontconfig fonts-config grub2 grub2-branding-SLE grub2-i386-pc grub2-snapper-plugin grub2-systemd-sleep-plugin grub2-x86_64-efi insserv-compat iproute2 iputils kernel-default less lvm2 net-tools net-tools-deprecated openssh openssh-askpass-gnome openssh-helpers parted patterns-base-apparmor patterns-base-base patterns-base-basesystem patterns-base-basic_desktop patterns-base-enhanced_base patterns-base-minimal_base patterns-base-x11 patterns-base-x11_enhanced patterns-fonts-fonts patterns-gnome-gnome_basic patterns-gnome-gnome_basis patterns-server-enterprise-oracle_server patterns-sles-apparmor patterns-sles-base patterns-yast-x11_yast patterns-yast-yast2_basis patterns-yast-yast2_desktop patterns-yast-yast2_server perl perl-Crypt-SmbHash perl-Digest-MD4 perl-Expect perl-IO-Socket-SSL perl-IO-Tty perl-LWP-Protocol-https perl-Net-SSLeay perl-SNMP perl-Tie-IxHash perl-XML-Writer perl-XML-XPathEngine plymouth plymouth-dracut puppet-agent ruby2.5 shim sudo susefirewall2-to-firewalld syslinux systemd systemd-bash-completion systemd-sysvinit tar telnet timezone unrar vim which yast2-firewall zip]


[ INFO ]: Processing: [ ] 0%
```

Comment: how are you building the docker image (what command and files (dockerfile perhaps) are you using)? Also what is `Kiwi`? I had not listened that before. Maybe the problem is related to: *"repos point to a local network machine"*. Are you sure the docker build can access to that network?

Comment: I you get stuck and not get any error, you can try running: `strace the_command_you_use`. The output might not be *readable* but sometimes you can know what's happening by checking the strace output.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.